# Continue caption numbering with different labels on Word 2019

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2019

I was writing my math paper, and I want to use Caption system to labelling the definitions, theorems, etc.. I am using heading numbering, so I can use heading number for caption. However, what my lecturer wants the numbering should be like this

**Definition 2.1.1** 
**Definition 2.1.2** 
**Theorem 2.1.3** 
**Proposition 2.1.4** 
**Theorem 2.1.5** 
(the last number continues in the same heading (2.1))

And what I got now is like this 
**Definition 2.1.1** 
**Definition 2.1.2** 
**Theorem 2.1.1** 
**Proposition 2.1.1** 
**Theorem 2.1.2** 
(the numbering of every label is separated)

Can I do this automatically in Word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You cannot, automatically. You can work around it.

The numbering is done using [SEQ Fields](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/numbering.htm#Sequence_Fields). See also [SEQ Field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-seq-sequence-field-062a387b-dfc9-4ef8-8235-29ee113d59be).

You want to change the SEQ field identifiers so they are all the same.

Here is my [article on dealing with fields](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501). You need to change the field codes. You can use the keyboard shortcut to toggle field codes. (Alt+F9 in Windows versions)

Conversely, if you do not need these in separate [tables of figures](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#TableFigures), you could create them all using the same label and simply edit the text in the Caption.